# Looking for a way to conveniently view Vanilla Minecraft questions

Tags: discussion, tags

As a player of Vanilla Minecraft, many of the Minecraft questions here would interest me. I usually navigate to that tag every time I visit this site.

One unfortunate navigation obsticle I have found was that I keep seeing questions for minecraft-feed-the-beast.

- I could put that as an ignored tag, which would help, but then the home page is wacky, because minecraft-feed-the-beast shows up as faded, but the games I have never heard of before are normal.
- I could make a search and bookmark it or memorize it, in fact I plan to, but this is not user-friendly. In fact, I visit this site with 4 computers, 2 of which are not mine, so bookmarking is not my first choice. For now, I have a link on my profile.

I know there has been much discussion about implicit hierarchy and so on, but I wanted to put my comments out there in case they would help you to create a better end solution.

My suggestion is that there be a way to subscribe minecraft/vanilla, which would essentially be minecraft without any mods, and if I was interested in specific mods, I could subscribe to those (minecraft/worldedit for example). The uninformed visitor could just subscribe to minecraft and they would not miss out on anything.

I do not know the proper way to implement this. I have very little idea what the proper interface would be for tagging. Ideally it would be something that is set up on the tag level and completely convenient at the question level. If I type minecraft as the only tag, then I need to be showing up in minecraft/vanilla. If I type minecraft/feed-the-beast, I need not be in minecraft/vanilla, but should still be in minecraft. Questions that relate to both would be specifically tagged with both /vanilla and /feed-the-beast

I would suggest that people still be able to just type plain minecraft, because a new user will not even know what a mod is and they will type just minecraft and it should automatically show up as minecraft/vanilla.

Sorry if this fails to count as a real question, but I think it is a useful comment and I am not sure the best place to post it.

Comment: The search would be "[minecraft] -[minecraft-feed-the-beast] -[whatever tag you want to ignore]".

Comment: I believe there is also a way to make the faded questions entirely invisible.

Comment: @RavenDreamer yes, it's in your profile page under prefs

Comment: The previous commentors have already outlined how to exclude tags from both questions you see on the site and searches. As far as the feature request go, I really don't see this happening - whatever solution you invent here would be significantly more complex than what we already have, and you're already complaining about how complex the current system is - " I don't remember how to make the search and I don't feel like going through this extra work during the time I am in the mood for gaming."

Comment: Also, we have no ability to implement new site features or change the way tags work. Code changes have to go directly through the StackExchange developers, and they are not very receptive to suggestions that would help only one site, especially if it's only a few users on one site.

Answer (score 2):

This Greasemonkey script could help:

[Unhide the Ignored Tags Hider](https://stackapps.com/q/2372/10706) puts the 'hide ignored tags' checkbox in the front page, to make it easier to toggle between hiding/fading ignored tags.